# Запрос с исключением SQL из двух таблиц

Tags: mysql, sql

есть две таблицы:

```
api_task

id | count
1  | 1
2  | 2
3  | 3
4  | 2
5  | 1
```

и

```
api_task_user

id | id_task | id_user
1  | 1       | 1
2  | 2       | 1
3  | 3       | 2
```

Допустим `id_user = 1`

В результате нужно получить `id` из `api_task` всех заданий, кроме тех, где в `api_task_user` `id_user = 1`

В результате должно быть так:

```
api_task

id | count
3  | 3
4  | 2
5  | 1
```

Если мои догадки верны, то нужно использовать:

```
SELECT at.*
FROM api_task at 
WHERE  
 NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
 FROM api_task_user
 WHERE api_task_user.user_id = 1
 );
```

Но, увы, это решение не работает.

UPD:

```
SELECT at.id,atu.user_id FROM api_task at LEFT JOIN api_task_user atu ON at.id = atu.id_task
```

Выдаёт:

```
id | user_id 
1  | 1
2  | 1
3  | NULL
```

Такой запрос:

```
SELECT at.id,atu.user_id FROM api_task at LEFT JOIN api_task_user atu ON at.id = atu.id_task WHERE atu.user_id != 1
```

Вообще ничего не выдаёт.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подобная задача достаточно часто решается с помощью left join. Мы получаем выборку, где у всех записей таблицы **api_task**, у которых нет пары по условию join в поле **b.id** пустое значение (null). Таким образом после join мы можем проверить условие **b.id is null** и получить желаемый результат.

p.s. синтаксис sqlite

```
select a.*
from api_task as a
left join api_task_user as b
on a.id = b.id
and b.id_user = 1
where  b.id is null
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает!

Answer (score 0):

1. Объединим обе таблицы в одну результирующую с нужными полями через `LEFT JOIN`
2. На полученный результат наложим фильтр `WHERE`

Comment: Добавил в вопрос

Comment: Единственное объяснение которое приходит в голову: в вопросе перепутаны названия таблиц: api_task и api_task_user; их нужно поменять местами в последнем запросе; Чтобы убедиться выполни select * from api_task

Comment: В вопросе всё правильно, поэтому и задал его, потому что сам ни к чему не пришёл :(

Comment: SELECT at.id FROM api_task at // У вас выдает 1,2,3 ? а в шапке вопроса 5-строк в этой таблице

Comment: Их вообще 3, ещё 2 добавил для понятности вопроса

Comment: необходимо в вопросе писать Реальное содержание таблиц, мы ведь не телепаты !

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106122/discussion-between-apelsin2020-and-santavital).